# Isotropy of pressure in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Under what conditions will pressure not be isotropic in a fluid? I know that for a fluid in equilibrium pressure must be isotropic otherwise there would be a flow developed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a general sense, pressure makes an isotropic contribution to the overall stress tensor.  For a viscous Newtonian fluid, the stress tensor can be resolved into an isotropic pressure (which does not depend on the rate of deformation), an isotropic portion that does depend on the rate of deformation, and a "deviatoric" (non-isotropic) part that that does depend on the rate of deformation.  If the fluid is not deforming, the stress tensor reduces to an isotropic pressure.

Comment: Ah ok. So for a non viscous fluid (not at equilibrium) the pressure will be isotropic whilst for a viscous fluid (not at equilibrium) this may not be the case? @Chester Miller

Comment: The pressure part of the stress tensor will always be isotropic.  But, for a deforming viscous fluid, the stress tensor, to which the isotropic pressure contributes, will not be isotropic.  For a viscous fluid, pressure is not the entire force per unit area; there is also an additional contribution to the force per unit area from viscous effects.  The total force per unit area is not referred to as the pressure if the fluid is deforming.

Comment: You could argue that the pressure part of the stress tensor is isotropic  *by definition*, and the reason it is defined that way is because it is a useful physical concept. As an example in 2D (just to make it easier) suppose the components of pressure on a small square element of incompressible fluid are $P_x$ and $P_y$ in the $x$ and $y$ directions. If $P_x \ne P_y$, the normal forces on the edges of the element can do *work* on the fluid, by deforming it into a rectangular shape with the same area. So it doesn't make sense to call this a *hydrostatic* pressure, unless $P_x = P_y$.

Comment: @alephzero:  Where have you been.  We miss you.

Answer (score 0):

It must be stressed tha the law of isotropic pressure for a fluid at rest  (Pascal's law) is only valid for a point of small dimensions but still large enough in order that continous medium hypotesis be valid. If the point is smaller than that the pressure (if such a term can be used) is anything but fluctuating (Bronwnian motion) https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03818957

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).