# Summation of fluid pressure and pressure as a physical quantity

Tags: fluid-statics

I recently started the chapter fluid statics and was reading through a book and also watching some videos. I read the fact that fluid pressure is ISOTROPIC at a point i.e same from all direction which made me ponder as pressure is usually dealt like a scalar and attaching drections to it is kind of a vector thing. This is my first confusion. As I continued in the chapter I saw a diagram of a small spherical (point sized) fluid particle with P pressure from all directions and they said the pressure on the point should be P; which is again confusing because shouldn't the pressure be the summation of all these P's that are acting round the fluid molecule and not just 'P' ? Where have misunderstood the concepts? Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hydrostatic pressure is a special case of stress: **equitriaxial stress**, meaning that the compressive stress in any direction—all three Cartesian axes—is identical.

This hopefully addresses both areas of confusion.

First, since only one unique vector quantity exists, namely, the inward force per unit area, we can just replace it with its scalar magnitude for convenience.

Second, the pressure isn't the summation of pressures, it *is* the pressure. The net force, which *is* the summation of all applied forces, is zero for a infinitesimal body of neutral buoyancy floating in a fluid.

Comment: I have a follow up question! What if the fluid is kept in a liquid accelerating with the container (relative acceleration wrt container is 0). Even in that case is pressure equitriaxial as u stated (identical in any direction)?
Thanks

Comment: Yes; this is equivalent to putting the liquid in a gravity field. The pressure will vary spatially (hydrostatic equilibrium) but is isotropic at any point.

Comment: Thanks alot and a last follow up question.
i) Is it same if the liquid is flowing (wrt to the container it has some velocity v). 
ii) I want to take a specific case of  test tube (in horizontal orientation) in which pressure had been artificially increased. Now I make a small orifice at the top of the testube and cover it up with another test tube (vertical orientation). Basically, 2 testubes are perpendicular to each other and the test tube that is lying flat has liquid under high pressure and hence the liquid will start flowing up in the vertical test tube. Is pressure isotropic over here?

Comment: btw thanks a ton:) You have been really helpful

Comment: Please see [this discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304483/isotropy-of-pressure-in-fluids).

Answer (score 0):

In general for a body, for each point there is a stress tensor. But as fluids don't have static shear stresses, the tensor becomes a diagonal matrix, with all elements equal to $-p$.

However, if we want to know the distribution of pressure with respect to depth, it is necessary to deal with forces and areas. For example, in a small cubic element, by symmetry the forces at sides are balanced. But if the downward force on the top surface is F, it must be supported by a upward force on the bottom part $F + w$ where $w$ is the weight of the element:

$$F_b - F_t = w \implies (p_h - p_{h-\Delta h})dxdy = \mu gdxdydh \implies \frac{dp}{dh} = \mu g $$

Integrating, we get the known expression: $p = \mu gh$, for each point a value of pressure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing out explicitly what the other answers addressed conceptually, that in general stress is a tensor:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\ \sigma_{ij} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{xx} & \tau_{xy} & \tau_{xz} \\
\tau_{yx} & \sigma_{yy} & \tau_{yz} \\
\tau_{zx} & \tau_{zy} & \sigma_{zz} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$$

with normal $\sigma$ and shear $\tau$ components.  In a static fluid, there are no shear components, and the normal components are all equal to the pressure $p$, negative because it's compressive.  This situation is called Hydrostatic Pressure

$$
\begin{equation*}
\ \sigma_{hyd} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-p & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -p & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -p
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$$

so strictly speaking, the actual stress state experienced by a given fluid particle is $\sigma_{hyd}$, but the only parameter in that state is the scalar pressure $p$.